# how to call foreach loop multiple time for extracting the data from data base

Tags: php, foreach

I want to extract array of data multiple times by using `foreach()` loop from database in php, I have one scenario given below.

Note `$results` is containing database data :

```
$values = array(10,20,30,40);

$datas = $results;

foreach($values as $value) {

    //some operations

    foreach($datas as $data)
    {
        $time = $data->time;
        // some operation

    } 
}
```

Here by doing DB-query I am extracting these data to "$results"

1528126233440,41602,48914,98,124,0,0,0

1528126248393,41602,48914,98,124,0,0,0

1528126251809,41602,48914,98,124,0,0,0

1528126256843,41602,48914,98,124,0,0,0

I have two different arrays

1. $values = array(10,20,30,40) // used for external loop
2. $datas = $results            //used for internal loop

where as "$reasults" contains the database data.

lets say

for 1st iteration of external loop and when it execute internal loop I  need this value [ [1528126233440, 41602], [1528126248393, 41602], [1528126251809, 41602], [1528126256843, 41602] ]

for 2nd iteration of external loop and wehen it execute internal loop I need this value  [ [1528126233440, 98], [1528126248393, 98], [1528126251809, 98], [1528126256843,  98] ]

like this..

so I my case the first iteration of external loop I am able to print [ [1528126233440, 41602], [1528126248393, 41602], [1528126251809, 41602], [1528126256843, 41602] ]

when it comes to the 2nd iteration of external loop the internal loop is not processing.

I need in each iteration of external `foreach()` loop the inner foreach() loop should run every time**.

But in my case for the first iteration the external loop is working, when it comes to second iteration of external loop at that time the second loop is not working.

Any suggestion will great help for me

Thank you

Comment: What you are saying is `Unclear`  Please sample data for `$results` ?

Comment: This sounds as if (it is unclear) you want to create multiple permutatins of the result you query from the database, with the permutations differing in the ``$values`` data provided. Two questions arise: 1. why do you need to query the database multiple times if the reuslt of the query is going to be the same in each outer iteration? And 2. maybe you could also create the permutations inside the query by means of a ``JOIN`` so that you have only one single resulting query, which indeed delivers a much bigger result then.